# how to parse a csv file which has some null value in java

Tags: java, csv

I want to parse csv like following :

> 12:50 AM,11.0,10.0,94,1013,10.0,NNW,14.8,-,N/A,,Mostly
>   Cloudy,330,2011-10-27 23:50:00

for parsing it I use a code like below :

```
while((mylines = rdr.readLine()) != null)
        {   
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<br />");
            mylines=mylines.replaceAll("<br />", "");
            System.out.println(mylines);
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(mylines , ",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            }
        }
```

for the 10th element which I call it Null I don't get any token response which is not good.
how can I get token for all the elements?

regards

Comment: Why does your CSV file contain html breaks?

Comment: what's the expected output and what's the actual output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected behavior of the `StringTokenizer` class. 
You can always force your program to return something, `"***"` for example for empty tokens by adding the following line right before splitting your string:

```
mylines=mylines.replaceAll(",,", ",***,");
```

In this case, the `StringTokenizer` will return `***` instead of `null`

Comment: What if the first value is null?

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable using a third-party library, use Apache's commons-lang and try `StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens()` - see [the API doc](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitPreserveAllTokens).

Answer (score 0):

At the tenth position, you have `,,`, which is an empty string, which in Java is represented by a null value. To avoid that the null value is printed, do something like

```
String str;
if((str = st.nextToken())!=null) {
  System.out.println(str);
} else {
  //print nothing or maybe a newline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a simple test case that parse the line and gives you all the elements including the empty one:

```
package com.sg2net.test;

public class TestSplit {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] data="12:50 AM,11.0,10.0,94,1013,10.0,NNW,14.8,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,330,2011-10-27 23:50:00§".split(",");
        //String[] data="valore##valore1".split("##");
        System.out.println(data.length);
        if (data.length>0) {
            int i=1;
            for (String element : data) {
                if (element==null || element.length()==0) {
                    System.out.println("empty element at position " + i);
                }
                System.out.println(element);
                i++;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of null, look for a token whose length is > 0. In Java, the value null is not the same as an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

[ostermiller.org](http://ostermiller.org/) has a [jar](http://ostermiller.org/utils/download.html) with nice utility-classes like [CSV-Parser/Writer](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html) etc.